# Read post meta values, only if posts are public

Tags: post-meta, wpdb, select

I want to retrieve meta_values applied to posts.

Currently I execute the following query

```
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix.'postmeta';
$values = $wpdb->get_results(
     "SELECT meta_value FROM $table WHERE meta_key = '$metakey' GROUP BY meta_value",
      ARRAY_A);
```

This returns all possible `meta_values`. Is there any possibility to retrieve only the `meta_values` of posts with `post_status` **published** (and not **private**).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, do an `INNER JOIN`, something like this should work:

```
$values = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts
      {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id
    WHERE meta_key= %s 
    AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status='publish'"
,$metakey
));
```

I changed `$wpdb->get_results()` to [`$wpdb->get_col()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Column) since it looks like you are just selecting a single column of data as an array.  I also added [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) since that is generally best practice.

Comment: Thanks, got it working for me now. My final **SELECT**-statement looked like `SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id WHERE meta_key = %s AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish' AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'event' ORDER BY meta_value"`